# Call one set of JS code instead of another

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, radio-button

I have a RF to L-band calculator/converter that I am designing and developing for my FT job. Now C-Band was easy as we only use one frequency range. KU band we have 2 frequency ranges. So for that calculator I want to use Radio Buttons. When an engineer Checks Radio 1 they use the functions coded for that Freqeuncy Range, if they Check Radio 2, they use the functions coded for that frequency range.

What can I do to call this when the radio is .checked?

Should I create an array of variables that assign functions to? I'm pretty new to JS. So let me know if I am not clear. TIA.

Comment: have each calculator as a function that will mess with the data.. `if(button.checked){calculatorFunction_1(your_data)} else{calculatorFunction_2(your_data)}` also where is the code? what are the errors?

Comment: I didn't get that far yet. I was asking for some direction before trying it out. I will fill in the code if I get it to work or if i don't.

Answer (score 0):

NVM. I think I figured out a work around.

I will use "If a is check var b = freqOne else b = freqTwo".

Comment: It's also possible, but if you match function names with radio values, then your solution will be easier to maintain and more elegant, please see my answer.

Comment: You can leave this as a comment only to the OP as you are also not sure if it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can match function names to radio button values

```js
function foo() {
    console.log("foo was called");
}

function bar() {
    console.log("bar was called");
}

function loremipsum() {
    console.log("loremipsum was called")
}

function test(item) {
    window[item.value]();
}
```

```html
<label>Foo <input type="radio" name="something" value="foo" onclick="test(this)"></label>
<label>Bar <input type="radio" name="something" value="bar" onclick="test(this)"></label>
<label>Lorem <input type="radio" name="something" value="loremipsum" onclick="test(this)"></label>
```

Comment: Ok. I need to clarify:

Each calculator already has 3 functions inside it:

Uplink Function
Downlink Function
Downlink to Uplink L-Band Function

So the Radio button would tell the page to use this set of functions, instead of that set of functions. Which is why i will just change the value of the freq with a boolean. Its all static formulas besides the input which is a range.

Comment: @CurtisRosler can you edit your question with code so I can look into it? I really believe that we are solving the same problem. But if-else blocks are not very easy to maintain, especially if the values change over time.